# How can I implement a flag module with caches but won't affect cache the flagging nodes?

Tags: 6, performance, flags

According to a post [here](http://www.ireckon.com/web-dev/cms/drupal/ubercart-product-comparison/), I have installed [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to implement product comparison. However I found that the CPU usage is very high 80-90%, then I tried to install [boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) and [Views content cache](http://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) to improve the performance. The result is good, CPU usage drop to around 10%, but when I flag(add) or unflag(remove) the node from the views, it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Views Content Cache has a [patch for flags support](https://www.drupal.org/node/1282056), although I don't know how well it will work with Boost.

Try using the [Views Flag Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh) module, it's supposed to tell the view when to refresh, don't know if it will play nice with the other modules though.